# Remove unwanted blank line eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, editor, settings, preferences

When i open any file in eclipse. it show alternative blank line after all the code lines and blank line. how can i remove it....

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In eclipse preference setting you can remove all the unwanted blank lines. Eclipse: Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit the formatter and following screen will pop up. [image]

And when you format the code all unwanted blank lines will be removed.

Comment: Better answer than using regex, but didn't work in luna

Answer (score 15):

Find: `^\s*\n`

Replace with: (empty)

Comment: this problem of setting but i dont know how can i resolved this issue.

Comment: Don't forget to choose "Regular expressions" in the find and replace dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't understand what Anshu said.
Do a Ctr-F on your editor.
**In the options, select Regular Expression.**
Enter ^\s*\n for the Find expression.
Keep the Replace box empty.
Replace All!

This of course might lead to removal of unwanted lines as well.

Comment: every new opened file has this problem.

Comment: Hmm, ok try this. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter. Create a New Formatting profile. When you do that you will see a bunch of tabs. One of them will be 'Blank Lines'. Here there are a bunch of customization options. You can play with these and apply the new profile to your project.

Comment: I get "Error Incompatible line delimiter near index 1748"

Answer (score 1):

Due to your eclipse setting.

you can change your setting from preferences.

Comment: whould you like send me version of eclipse IDE

Comment: in Eclipse 3.7.2 you just right click on left side of editor , according to you print screen , you just RC below yellow triangle show

Answer (score 1):

1. Find and replace as Regular Expressions with ^\s*\n
2. Press Ctrl + Shift + f
3. Press Ctrt + Shift + o

Answer (score 0):

The good thing is that this is all well and good when you work alone; 
The unfortunate side is that it also exposes "bad team cooperation" when you check in your files in the version control: there will be people who will gladly help you keep things consistent while there are many others who will ignore your pleas and keep overwriting your beautifully properly formatted code.