# Is there a way to automatically remove trailing spaces in Eclipse?

Tags: java

Is there a way to automatically remove trailing spaces in Eclipse?

I see there are nice functionality in Source like Correct Indentation and Format.
But they dont remove trailing spaces.

Thanks

PS: What other functionalities of this kind you use to make the code nicer?

Comment: Have you try to make your own Code Fromatter Template ? There are whole  lot of options in there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740086/remove-unwanted-blank-line-eclipse-editor this works for me

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's available as a Save action, at least. (I can't see it under the formatter options.)

Go to Window / Preferences, Java / Editor / Save Actions. Tick "Additional Actions" and click on Configure. In the "Code Organizing" tab, the first option is "Remove trailing whitespace".

Note that this will remove *all* trailing whitespace from Java files - not just those you've touched. If you're working with people who *don't* remove trailing whitespace, this can be messy in terms of later doing a diff.

Comment: But it is a good practice in general to remove trailing white space, so even in a large team it would be good to enforce such a global codestyle rule.

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu: Well, there are numerous factors which get involved - including whether everyone's using tools which *do* remove trailing whitespace easily. That's an argument I don't want to get into here - I just wanted to give a heads-up as a warning.

Comment: numerous of files changed and hope gonna have great time with GIT

Comment: It's kind of crazy how far you have to dig to find this option, the answer is much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this option, and it would've taken me forever to find it on my own.

Answer (score 20):

You can easily remove all the trailing whitespace within a single file by using a regular expression with the Find/Replace dialog. Enter **[ \t]+$** in the "*Find:*" box and leave the "*Replace with:*" box empty. Check the "*Regular expressions*" option then click "*Replace All*"

Comment: Great solution! Why is there no shortcut or toolbar/menu item for this easy task? I don't want to apply it as a save action, but every now and then, when I feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the plugin "AnyEdit" from http://andrei.gmxhome.de/eclipse/.
This tool removes the whitespace in every file type on save.