# How to remove the empty line Or space between the numbers

Tags: eclipse, annotations, line, settings, space

How to remove the empty line Or space between the numbers on Eclipse as it appears in the attached photo.

[image: Spaces]

Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Format

Comment: The space is probably caused by having word wrapping or code minings enabled (unfortunately your screenshot is cropped, so it is not possible to tell which of the two it is causing).

Comment: Already solution is available in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740086/remove-unwanted-blank-line-eclipse-editor).